# applet->JWS application <-> Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, security, java-web-start

I have searched SO and Google over a score of hours and I still cannot find an answer to how to deploy a JWS application (not applet) from a webpage and call methods on it or even have it call methods in Javascript.  Can someone instruct, show an API.  If this cant be done then RIA and browser content will forever be oil and water.  Excuse the naivete, I am nonplused on this.

Comment: JWS is *super* deprecated and most browsers don't allow Java in any form anymore, so you may want to consider other tech.

Comment: @ssube
What technologies are available to call native app methods from a browser page.  Is Oracle really giving up that easily and abandon Java on client-side to the demands of Apple and Google, et. al.?

Comment: @ssube Despite the changes by browser manufacturers, JWS is not deprecated, let alone *super* deprecated. OP allowing interaction between JS in a browser and an app. is a potential security hole the size of a barn door. It is not a surprise (to me at least) that they shut the door.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
What is OP?  What is/are the technologies to have a JWS application communicate to a browser?  They are silos now it is almost pre-plugin days.  What is Oracle's roadmap for this?  Please edify.

Comment: *"What is OP?"* Original Poster - you. *"What is/are the technologies to have a JWS application communicate to a browser?"* Voodoo? Is voodoo a technology? *"What is Oracle's roadmap for this?"* Shrug and say 'screw it'. See [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: @AndrewThompson
So Andrew, are you saying through the sarcasm, that there is no technologies to have a JWS application communicate with the browser?  I am asking the question in good faith can you or others respond equally?